# Main site's sidebar and Meta site's sidebar don't match anymore

Tags: support, bug

I've been noticing this for a few days, the Main site's sidebar and the Meta site's sidebar don't match anymore:

[image: s1] [image: s2]

In particular I've been noticing the difference between the "Hot Meta Posts" section: the "Hot Meta Posts" section on the Meta site's sidebar always seems to be reporting additional items compared to the "Hot Meta Posts" section on the Main site's sidebar, and now also a missing "Featured on Meta" section on the Meta site's sidebar stands out.

Is this intentional?

**Edit**: the current status of the two sidebars should confirm that the additional item on the "Hot Meta Posts" section on the Meta site's sidebar was not due to the missing featured MSE post:

[image: s3]  [image: s4]

Notice also the different order of the items in the "Hot Meta Posts" section.

I'm not sure how the items are sorted (possibly in a descending "hotness" order?), so this might be just about a delay in the update of one of the two.

It's not even really a problem, it's just that IIRC they used to be synchronized, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to be an "out-of-sync" problem, I couldn't catch the two sidebars matching even once since I first noticed the problem.

Comment: I'd guess that meta is showing one more hot meta post because it isn't showing the featured MSE post.

Comment: @Seth This started happening before the MSE post was featured, I'm pretty positive about that. I'd say at least since a week.

Comment: @Seth I'll update the question with new screenshots as soon as the MSE post is not featured anymore to make sure that's actually the case, but on a side note is it expected that the MSE post doesn't show up on Meta?

Comment: Eagle-eyes!  **;-)**

Comment: I distinctly recall reading that hot posts are shown to fill up the sidebar, after other things like featured posts are shown. Now where did I see that?

Comment: @muru I'm wondering the same, because I believe that's correct itself, but I'm also pretty positive this started happening before the MSE post was even featured, i.e. IIRC the Meta site's sidebar would have shown an item more compared to the Main site's bar even at that time. I'll check this again once the MSE post is not featured anymore, but I'm pretty sure I've noticed anomalies even before that.